# How to clear a UITextView with a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am attempting to make a UIButton that will clear a UITextView that I have set for the output. When the user has seen what they want to see, they click OK and it clears it and they can start again. The code I have set up for it is this and I can not figure out why it will not work, I just click the button a hundred times and nothing happens.

```
@IBAction func okButton(sender: UIButton) {
    resultOutputLabel.text == ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not == , you should use =

```
resultOutputLabel.text = ""
```

For assign a value you should use = sign, == use for comparison purpose. Such as

```
 let a = 5  
 let b = 5

if a == b {
   // a value = b value
 }
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, that is the most embarrassing mistake ever... I should have known that. Thanks though, would have taken me an hour to find that

Comment: Up Vote from SL ;)